# Mocking a pointer to a pointer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, mocking, ocmock

I'm trying to mock a call to NSURLConnection. I swizzle the class method call with my own that calls my mock object. I'm trying to implement the mock like this:

```
[[[[urlConnectionMock expect] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    NSURLResponse * __autoreleasing *responsePointer;
    [invocation getArgument:&responsePointer atIndex:3];
    id response = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:NSHTTPURLResponse.class];
    [[[response stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((NSInteger){ 200 })] statusCode];
    *responsePointer = response;
}] andReturn:encryptedResponse] sendSynchronousRequest:OCMOCK_ANY returningResponse:OCMOCK_ANY error:OCMOCK_ANY];
```

The problem is that OCMOCK_ANY is an Objective-C pointer, not a pointer to a pointer (the compiler rightly complains). Before I dig more deeply into the OCMock source, perhaps someone can suggest how to get around this? Full credit given if you have a better approach entirely.

Comment: A shot in the dark as I don't have any OCMock projects up and running right now and haven't worked with it in a long time - have you tried `[OCMArg anyPointer]`?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Yes, gave that a shot -- no dice. I think I might be able to extent OCMArg and implement NSURLResponse **... That's my plan for tomorrow anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. By-reference is already built into OCMock.

```
id fakeResponse = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:NSHTTPURLResponse.class];
[[[fakeResponse stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((NSInteger){ 200 })] statusCode];
[[[urlConnectionMock expect] andReturn:encryptedResponse] sendSynchronousRequest:OCMOCK_ANY returningResponse:[OCMArg setTo:fakeResponse] error:[OCMArg setTo:nil]];
```

This is so much happier looking as well!